# help with C# code for fast search

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this code that can do fast search on database.

it works excellent on sqlCE.

now i need to translate that it will work on Access 2007

how to do it ?

```
public bool LOOK()
        {
            Tmp = "";
            MAK = "";
            DES = "";
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            Cmd.CommandText = "BarcodeTbl";
            Cmd.IndexName = "Barcode";
            Cmd.SetRange(DbRangeOptions.Match, new object[] { txtYad.Text }, null);
            SqlCeDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                Tmp = read[2].ToString(); 
                MAK = read[0].ToString(); 
                DES = read[1].ToString();
            }
            read.Dispose();
            if (Tmp == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                txtYad.Text = DES;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the classes from the [System.Data.OleDb namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb%28VS.71%29.aspx), for example `OleDbDataReader`, `OleDbCommand` etc.

As an aside, the following:

```
SqlCeDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (read.Read())
 {
     Tmp = read[2].ToString(); 
     MAK = read[0].ToString(); 
     DES = read[1].ToString();
 }
 read.Dispose();
```

Can be better written as:

```
using(SqlCeDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        Tmp = read[2].ToString(); 
        MAK = read[0].ToString(); 
        DES = read[1].ToString();
     }
} // .Dispose() is called automatically here
```